# Create copy of uploaded File object, including its metadata, for http POST request

Tags: json, ajax, http, browser, server

[Built-in methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) in the browser allow me to view a file's metadata once I've uploaded it:

```
// console logging actual uploaded file
{
    lastModified: 1448847181000,
    lastModifiedDate: Sun Nov 29 2015 20:33:01 GMT-0500 (EST),
    name: "dummypano.jpg",
    preview: "blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3000/6f60ac53-08ab-4e4c-a18d-91809324b965",
    size: 8221818type: "image/jpeg",
    webkitRelativePath: ""
}
```

Interestingly, this `file` is not a typical object. I cannot send this metadata to the server, as a lot of its attributes get lost when I stringify the file (second log).

```
// console logging stringified file
{"preview":"blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3000/6f60ac53-08ab-4e4c-a18d-91809324b965"}
```

Does anyone know how of a trick to create a copy of this object so I can post it to the server? Furthermore, why is the `preview` attribute the only one that gets stringified?

Comment: please don't use screenshots .. paste the actual code into a code window for us.

Comment: Apologies @Zak I'll do that